# How do i check if array not contains another array on Ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 4 and i'd like to know how could I check if an array is NOT on other array to make a condition, but it doesn't work, what i'm doing wrong?

```
  method() {
    if (!this.array.includes(['Web development', 'Football'])
      ) {
        console.log(this.array)
        //doSomething
      }
```

**UPDATED**

once click on a button, imDone method starts. What i want exactly is once clicked, if the iDislike array (all this words) arent on the arrayChip, then do something

```
  ngOnInit() {    
this.arrayChip = [
  '4',
  "4",
  '5',
  '5',
  '7',
  '34',
  '1',
  '9',
  '7',
  '9',
  '4',
  '3',]
  }

  imDone() {
    let iDislike = ['Web 3', '2', '4', '5', '6']
    const includesListOfItemsToCheck = this.arrayChip.some(subArray => 
      iDislike.every(item => subArray.includes(item)));    
    console.log(includesListOfItemsToCheck)

    console.log('arrayChip: ' + this.arrayChip)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array.includes only works with primitive values like strings & numbers..
And you can't compare two arrays using === in JavaScript

so something like this should do the job -

```js
const array = [['Soap'], ['Web development', 'Football'], ['Globe', 'Science', 'Spartan']]
const listOfItemsToCheck = ['Web development', 'Football']
const includesListOfItemsToCheck = array.some(subArray => subArray.every(item => listOfItemsToCheck.includes(item)));
console.log(includesListOfItemsToCheck);
```

Here I'm using Array.some which will return a boolean value if any item in the array satisfies the condition in my return statement.
And Array.every which will return a boolean value determining whether every item in the array satisfies the condition in the return statement.

## Update to answer the updated question:

```js
  const arrayChip = ['4',"4",'5','5','7','34','1','9','7','9','4','3']
  const iDislike = ['Web 3', '2', '4', '5', '6']
  const allIDislikeDoesntExistInArrayChip = iDislike.every(item => !arrayChip.includes(item))
console.log(allIDislikeDoesntExistInArrayChip)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, theres no other way easier? it seems too much complicated to me to understand this logic

Comment: By the way... it gives an error "subArray.every is not a function" why?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe i didnt say it correctly i just want to check if 3 strings are into an array.... that's all

Comment: if you want to check if 3 strings are in an array as opposed to checking that the subArray is equal to the listOfItemsToCheck you can do 
```const includesListOfItemsToCheck = array.some(subArray => listOfItemsToCheck.every(item => subArray.includes(item)));
``` instead. This is really easy and readable once you understand Array.some and Array.every, the Alternative would be doing nested forEach loops, which would uglier, more verbose and less readable IMO.

Comment: @M.Mariscal running the answer on the browser works fine and returns true as expected, can you show me your updated code? Also checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: @M.Mariscal I've updated my answer, here in the updated version its not a nested array, so you can just use Array.every which returns a boolean indicating whether every item in the iDislike array doesn't exist in the arraychip one

Comment: Thank you really very much, you saved me! have a nice day!